# How can i access a ViewController that's a segue from a Tableview in another ViewController from my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to CoreData, and my problem is that i want to make an NSManagedObject from a ViewController Class that has a table view, basically i want to save an object inside a tableView "every time the user adds a cell", but that ViewController is presented from a tableview menu, "object at index", the question is, how can i save data for that
 ViewController from my AppDelegate? or how can i access that ViewController From my AppDelegate...

Here's an image of my Storyboard and somehow explaining what I'm trying to achieve.
[image: My StoryBoard]

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you want to save the data from the app delegate? Why not save it in the controller where you're changing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read through your question ten times and i don't seem to be understanding it fully.

From what i understand you want to save the data into core data from the bottom tableviewcontroller which is a UIViewController with an UITableView as a subview.

I don't see how that should be difficult unless i understood the problem wrong.

The basic Xcode template for an iOS project using Core Data implements the initialization within the app delegate but relying on the app delegate as a connector is something i don't do. I always abstract that information into a singleton which can be accessed from any class that implements that logic.

Also the basic Xcode template for a core data project also contains logic for adding entries within the tableview so i would recommend looking at that.

If you want specific example source code i can do that but i recommend looking at the core data template.

Comment: Thanks!!! I solved the problem within the viewcontroller, im new to coredata and i didnt quite well understood how to implement it